# Is it possible to limit "each in" in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, rss

I'm writing a RSS Reader using Meteor. The server parses the .rss/.xml and splits it in several items that get written into a collection.

On Client-Side the feed items get displayed. How can i limit the number of items displayed on the page ? I tried to limit it in the return statement but that's not working.

```
{{#each item in feed_item}}
       <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <h3><a href="{{item.Link}}" target="_blank">{{item.Title}}</a></h3>
                  <h4>{{item.PubDate}}</h4>
                  <h5>{{item.Website}}</h5>
                  <p>{{item.Description}}</p>
             </div>
        </div>
{{/each}}


db_feed_item = new Meteor.Collection("feed_item");

Template.feed.helpers({

    'feed_item': function () {

        return db_feed_item.find({} , {sort: {PubDate: -1}}, {limit: 10});
    }
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be just one object for options. Replace

```
{sort: {PubDate: -1}}, {limit: 10}
```

with

```
{sort: {PubDate: -1}, limit: 10}
```

Comment: Working ! Thank you :)